# Line, column in RichTextBox, WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I am wondering how to update my status bar with line and column number automatically using the RichTextBox in WPF.

First of all, which event do I hook on to? My box is multiline. KeyDown doesn't react to caret up and down movement.

The line number can be computer using:

```
int someBigNumber = int.MaxValue;
int lineMoved, currentLineNumber;
editor.CaretPosition.GetLineStartPosition(-someBigNumber, out lineMoved);
currentLineNumber = -lineMoved + 1;
status_bar.Text = "Line " + currentLineNumber.ToString();
```

How do I get the column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question is really old but I just solved it after having the issue myself.

[c# WPF Line and Column number from RichTextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994674/c-sharp-wpf-line-and-column-number-from-richtextbox)